# codeigniter pass data from view to model and retrieve info

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Here is the thing:
I have controller that retrieve data from database and pass info to view. In the view I have a loop like this:

```
foreach ($myphotos->result() as $myphoto){
echo $myphoto->p_id
}
```

But in that loop I need to pick up $myphoto->p_id and ask database to retrieve me users with this p_id.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_id IN (SELECT u_id FROM p_votes WHERE p_id = 268);
```

and in:

```
foreach ($myphotos->result() as $myphoto){
echo $myphoto->p_id
$this->load->model('m_member');
$users_voted = $this->m_member->getUsersVotedOnImage($myphoto->p_id);
foreach ($users_voted->result() as $users){
echo '<div id="voterfooter">voted:<a href="$users->i_id">'.$users->name.</a>
}
}
```

Ok that was one option that I come up, but there is also another option, but select statement is so complicated!

here is how:
I already have this one:

```
SELECT * FROM photos WHERE p_id NOT IN (SELECT distinct p_id FROM p_votes where u_id = ".$this->session->userdata('u_id').") LIMIT ".$segment_url.", ".$config['per_page'];
```

But how to pick up also from users people that voted on that picture and print it in view?

Here is database scheme:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `u_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `fb_id` varchar(255),
  `fb_url` varchar(255),
  `email` varchar(100),
  `username` varchar(100),
  `name` varchar(100),
  `lastname` varchar(100),
  `mini_pic_fb` varchar(255),
  `mini_pic` varchar(255),
  `country` varchar(100),
  `place` varchar(100),
  `address` varchar(100),
  `nr` int(10),
  `postcode` varchar(10),
  `pass` varchar(35),
  `active` varchar(35),
  `activation_code` varchar(42),
  PRIMARY KEY  (`u_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `fb_id` (`fb_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=229 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `photos` (
  `p_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `u_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `p_date` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `p_content` longtext NOT NULL,
  `p_title` text NOT NULL,
  `p_photo` text NOT NULL,
  `p_small` text NOT NULL,
  `p_thumb` text NOT NULL,
  `p_up` bigint(20),
  `p_down` bigint(20),
  PRIMARY KEY  (`p_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=229 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `p_votes` (
  `pv_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `u_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `p_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `pv_date` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `pv_ip` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`pv_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=229 ;
```

Comment: for better practices : don't use models in you're view , send all the data you need to the view in the first place .

Comment: That's what I want to avoid, but can't find solution to this!

Comment: What you need are joins! I suggest googling for that term.

Comment: Yes I could use joins, but it will be 3 tables to join! is this possible

Comment: How I see it's not about sql statment, but about calling in the foreach loop sql statment, but from view I don't want to call model! It would be easy if I in that foreach could call one more foreach

Answer (score 0):

I braked MVC pattern but I didn't know how to do this other way!
If someone knows how to do this without breaking MVC please respond!
In the view:

```
foreach ($myphotos->result() as $myphoto){
       $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_id IN (SELECT u_id FROM p_votes WHERE p_id = ".$myphoto->p_id.")";
    $voters = $this->db->query($query)->result();

        echo $myphoto->p_title;
        foreach($voters as $row){
        echo '<div id="voterfooter">';
    echo '<a href="'.base_url().'clanovi/clan/'.$row->u_id.'">';
    echo $row->name.' '.$row->lastname.'</a>';
    echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm no PHP expert, but you asked me personnally to look into it... Here's one option, can you create a list of lists in your controller and return it to your view? Something like `[ ($myphoto->p_title, [($row->u_id, $row->name, $row->lastname),($row2...),]), ($myphoto2...,[]), ...]`?